# Very slow rendering of GridLayout ListView - WinJS

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-8, winjs

this is my first Windows 8 app... I'm having this last problem before going live with it. :)

**I have a ListView with layout set to GridLayout. The app adds 50 items to the ListView's datasource when the main page is loaded. The ListView takes 5-6 seconds to render.**

**NB:** 5-6 seconds after the items have been added to the dataSource. XHR/AJAX call + loading takes 200-300ms.

---

This seems very weird. I've added some code below:

**JS - Defining the ListView and Data Source**

```
this.categoryProducts = new WinJS.Binding.List();
this.productListview = element.querySelector('#category-products-listview').winControl;
this.productListview.itemTemplate = element.querySelector('#product-template');
this.productListview.itemDataSource = this.categoryProducts.dataSource;
this.productListview.oniteminvoked = this._product_clicked.bind(this);
```

**JS - Adding items to Data Source**

```
_ref = data.products;
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
   product = _ref[_i];
   _results.push(Category.categoryProducts.push(product));
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="product-template" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="item product">
        <img class="item-image" src="/images/shopping-bag.png" data-win-bind="src: thumbnail; alt: name" onError="this.src='/images/shopping-bag.png';" />

        <div class="item-details" >
            <div class="item-details-top">
                <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: name"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="item-details-bottom">
                <div  class="price"> <span style="font-weight:bold;">$</span> <span data-win-bind="textContent: price"></span></div> 
                <div class="reviews" ><span class="icon-comments"></span> <span data-win-bind="textContent: reviews_count"></span></div> 
                <div class="stars" > <span class="icon-star"></span><span class="icon-star"></span><span class="icon-star"></span><span class="icon-star"></span><span class="icon-star"></span>  <span data-win-bind="textContent: stars"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

This is what the ListView looks like when rendered.

[image]

---

Any idea guys?

Comment: What if you add all the items to the datasource before you are passing the datasource to the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you add items to the dataSource before or after you set up the ListView?  Not saying this is it, but wondering if you are getting a lot of churn by adding items the way you are.  I would pull down the items and create a new Binding List and then set the dataSource.

I have loaded 100s of items into a listView with minimal delay.

1. Set up ListView with empty List
2. Pull data from web
3. Create new Binding List with results from web call
4. Update ListView with new datasource from new List

Your mileage may vary...

Comment: Strangely... that worked! First column loads almost immediately, other columns are delayed. Also... I have to thank you for your Youtube videos! They really helped me during the first few days of development. :)

Comment: Apologies for pulling a bit... but would have any idea why only the first column would load instantly? The other columns still have a delay. Thanks :)